# （usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-w WEIGHTS] [-m]）というエラーがJupyter Notebookの実行時に出てしまう

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

[任意のSignal-to-Noise比の音声波形をPythonで作ろう！](https://engineering.linecorp.com/ja/blog/voice-waveform-arbitrary-signal-to-noise-ratio-python/)

こちらのサイトのプログラムをJupyter Notebookを利用してノイズ除去を試みているのですが、以下のエラーメッセージが起きてしまいます。

こちらの解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

エラーメッセージ

```py
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] --clean_file CLEAN_FILE --noise_file NOISE_FILE
                             [--output_clean_file OUTPUT_CLEAN_FILE] [--output_noise_file OUTPUT_NOISE_FILE]
                             --output_noisy_file OUTPUT_NOISY_FILE --snr SNR
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: --clean_file, --noise_file, --output_noisy_file, --snr
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

ソースコード

```
import argparse
import array
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import wave


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--clean_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--noise_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--output_clean_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noise_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noisy_file', type=str, default='', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--snr', type=float, default='', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()

    clean_file = args.clean_file
    noise_file = args.noise_file
    snr = args.snr

    clean_wav = wave.open(clean_file, "r")
    noise_wav = wave.open(noise_file, "r")
```

関連サイトやTeratailに載っていた質問等を試してみたのですが、思うような結果にならず同じようなエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

以下に参考サイトを添付しておきます。

- [普通のpython実行ファイル(argparseを含むファイル)をJupyter notebookで実行するときのメモ書き](https://qiita.com/LittleWat/items/6e56857e1f97c842b261)
- [Jupyter lab / notebookで argparseそのままで実行する方法](https://qiita.com/uenonuenon/items/09fa620426b4c5d4acf9)
- [Python3 Jupyter notebook使用時のエラー（usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-w WEIGHTS] [-m]）について](https://teratail.com/questions/185053)

Comment: 提示されているのは呼び出される側のソースコードと思われますが、提示が必要なのは呼び出す側のソースコードでしょう。エラーメッセージに書かれている通り、指定が必須であるパラメータ(か、それに対応する値)が指定されていないということでしょうから。呼び出す側のソースコードを追記してください。あるいは、今提示されている呼び出される側のソースコードが参照記事の下から2つ目のQiitaの記事の内容を反映していないようなので、それを反映してみるというのも手でしょう。あるいはJupyterにこだわらずコマンドラインやコンソールから実行すれば良いのでは？

Comment: すみません。このエラーについて調べていたら、'--clean_file'やその下の部分にファイルの絶対パスを入力していないから起こったものだと分かりました。

Comment: Qiitaの記事を見て、args = parser.parse_args(args=['--clean_file',"onsei.wav", '--noise_file', "noise.wav", '--snr',0])　この形で実行したら消えました。ただ、別のエラー　ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size　が出てしまったのでそちらは別の質問でします。ありがとうございます。