# the following arguments are requiredエラーについて

Tags: python, python3

任意のSignal-to-Noise比の音声波形をPythonで作ろう！
https://engineering.linecorp.com/ja/blog/voice-waveform-arbitrary-signal-to-noise-ratio-python/

こちらのプログラムを実行した所、以下のメッセージが出ました。
これの解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

stn.py: error: the following arguments are required: C:\Users\アカウント名\onsei.wav, C:\Users\アカウント名\noise.wav, --snr

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
usage: stn.py [-h] [--output_clean_file OUTPUT_CLEAN_FILE]
              [--output_noise_file OUTPUT_NOISE_FILE]
              [--output_noisy_file OUTPUT_NOISY_FILE] --snr SNR
              C:\Users\アカウント名\onsei.wav C:\Users\アカウント名\noise.wav
stn.py: error: the following arguments are required: C:\Users\アカウント名\onsei.wav, C:\Users\アカウント名\noise.wav, --snr
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import argparse
import array
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import wave

clean_file = 音声ファイル
noise_file = ノイズファイル

snr = 20


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(clean_file, type=str)
    parser.add_argument(noise_file, type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--output_clean_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noise_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noisy_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument(snr, type=float)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()

    clean_file = args.clean_file
    noise_file = args.noise_file
    snr = args.snr

    clean_wav = wave.open(clean_file, "r")
    noise_wav = wave.open(noise_file, "r")
```

Comment: 参照元のプログラムに修正を加えているようですが、元のコードは実行時の引数でパラメータを取得しているはずなので、エラーが出た際にどのように実行したのかも質問に追記してください。

Comment: [以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/83570/26370)と同様に、呼び出される側のソースコードだけではなく、呼び出す側でどのような指定を行ったかの情報が必要と思われます。参照先記事に書かれているGitHubリポジトリ[Sato-Kunihiko/audio-SNR](https://github.com/Sato-Kunihiko/audio-SNR)の[Usage](https://github.com/Sato-Kunihiko/audio-SNR#usage)の`Example of ...`に書かれたコマンドラインのようなものとか、その部分をプログラム化しているならばそのソースコードとかを提示しないと、助言・回答を得るのは難しいのでは？

Comment: https://github.com/Sato-Kunihiko/audio-SNR#usage
こちらのreadmeを参考に

pip install pipenv
↓
pipenv install
↓
pipenv shell

をした後に
create_mixed_audio_file.py
を実行しています。